# How to use transistor models provided as Spice netlists in KiCad?

Tags: kicad

I would like to use device models provided by EPC for their GaN MOSFETs in a KiCad simulation. The models (https://epc-co.com/epc/DesignSupport/DeviceModels.aspx) are provided as subcircuit Spice netlists. Can I create a new sub-schematic, import the netlist into the schematic, then create a symbol for the sub-schematic and use it in another schematic for simulation?

Comment: I don't know KiCad well, but IIRC you should be able to have an "edit SPICE model", or similar, for symbols that are placed in the schematic (i.e. place a relevant symbol, edit it, and add your SPICE library). If this is not true, it might be better to search for more in their help, or go to their forums.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen - Thank you for suggestion, it was actually as simple as that. For reference if some will have a similar question:
1) Create a symbol and place it on schematic.
2) Right click on the symbol Properties->Edit Properties->Edit Spice Model
3) In the tab Model in the field Library select the file where subcircuit exists, in the field Type select Subcircuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference if some will have a similar question:

1. Create a symbol and place it on schematic.
2. Right click on the symbol Properties->Edit Properties->Edit Spice Model
3. In the tab Model in the field Library select the file where subcircuit exists, in the field Type select Subcircuit.